# Showing that a representation is trivial using determinants

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group with generators $g_1, \ldots g_n$ satisfying some generating relations. Let $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\rho_V:G \to \textrm{GL}(V)$ be a well-defined representation of $G$ such that $\textrm{det}(\rho_V(g_i))=1$ for all $i$.

Now, $\Lambda^2V$ (the anti-symmetric tensor square) is one-dimensional, and since $\textrm{det}(\rho_V(g_i))=1$ for all $i$, the anti-symmetric tensor square representation is trivial.

I don't understand why the matrices having determinant $1$ makes the representation trivial. Sorry if the question is vague, I can't find the exam paper anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exterior square of $\Bbb C^2$ is one-dimensional. In general the dimension
of $\bigwedge^k\Bbb C^n$ is $\binom nk$. If $A:\Bbb C^n\to \Bbb C^n$
is a linear map, it induces maps $\bigwedge^kA:\bigwedge^k\Bbb C^n\to
\bigwedge^k\Bbb C^n$. In particular, $\bigwedge^nA$ is just multiplication by $\det A$.

In your example, $n=2$, and $\det(\rho(g))=1$ for all $g\in G$, so that $\bigwedge^2\rho(g)$ is the identity map on $\bigwedge^2V$ for all $g\in G$.